# jQuery edge to edge circular slider/carousel

Tags: jquery-plugins, carousel

I am working on developing a jQuery slider that goes edge to edge on any screen width and is circular (so you can just keep going in either direction).  Is there anything prebuilt for this?  You can see my attempt at http://siegedesign.com/io-dev/payoff/.  It has a number of issues so I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: We were able to avoid all issues on this with the current configuration without using a new plugin.  you can access the above URL for a while, but when the site launches it will be at http://www.progpayoff.com/.

Comment: A login was required so you can see this at ids.io-web.com/payoff